# open model zoo multi_camera_multi_target_tracking_demo

Tags: python, computer-vision, openvino

Am trying [multi_camera_multi_target_tracking_demo](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/tree/master/demos/multi_camera_multi_target_tracking_demo/python) with test video files, running the demo on Ubuntu with:

```
$ python3.9 multi_camera_multi_target_tracking_demo.py -i ./test_video/test1.mp4 ./test_video/test1.mp4 --m_detector intel/person-detection-retail-0013.xml --m_reid intel/person-reidentification-retail-0277.xml
```

But I encounter an error:

```
RuntimeError: Check 'false' failed at src/inference/src/core.cpp:100:
[ NETWORK_NOT_READ ] Unable to read the model: intel/person-detection-retail-0013.xml Please check that model format: xml is supported and the model is correct. Available frontends: paddle pytorch tflite tf ir onnx
```

From what I understand the script wants onnx format and I am using xml format. Can someone give me a tip on how to redownload onnx format model?

when I cloned the [open model zoo](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/tree/master) repo I used the directions `omz_downloader --all` and `omz_converter --all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone the specific branch for Open Model Zoo 2022.3.0 if you're using OpenVINO 2022.3.0:

```
git clone --depth 1 -b 2022.3.0 https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo.git
```

Additionally, you can download the individual model using the following command:

```
omz_downloader --name person-detection-retail-0013
omz_downloader --name person-reidentification-retail-0277
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the path of the models slightly wrong, and that's why the program is not finding them.

If you call `omz_downloader --all` from the same location of the python program, then the models will be downloaded to `./intel/MODEL_NAME/FPXX/MODEL_NAME.[xml,bin]`.

So, to actually call the program with the correct model paths you should call it like this for example(if using the FP32 version):

```
python3.9 multi_camera_multi_target_tracking_demo.py -i ./test_video/test1.mp4 ./test_video/test1.mp4 --m_detector intel/person-detection-retail-0013/FP32/person-detection-retail-0013.xml --m_reid intel/person-reidentification-retail-0277/FP32/person-reidentification-retail-0277.xml
```